# Why do my column header HTML helpers not work when using a custom View Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created a 'ViewModel' because I want more stuff available to iterate through and display in my View.  To keep this simple in this example my ViewModel does nothing more than if I had not used it at all.  Also I am using Enitity Framework so ActionRequest is ultimately a table in SQL Server if this matters.

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class ActionRequestVM
{
    public IEnumerable<ActionRequest> ARVM { get; set; }
}
```

In my View, before I had:

```
@model IEnumerable<PocoExp5.Models.ActionRequest>
```

and now with my ViewModel I have:

```
@model PocoExp5.ViewModels.ActionRequestVM
```

I can iterate through my data just fine and it all displays using:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ARVM) { ...
```

However, the column headers, for example:

```
 @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RequestID)
```

no longer work.  I thought I could just do something like:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ARVM.RequestID)
```

but that doesn't work.  So there is something I fundamentally do not understand here?

Comment: DisplayNameFor is going to return a static string each time, are you sure you dont need LabelFor(x => x.ARVM.RequestID) ?
Are the properties in your ActionRequest class marked with [Display(Name="Request ID")] decorations?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are missing the point here. Since you Model.ARVM is essentially a list of ActionRequest objects then doing:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ARVM.RequestID)
```

does nothing since RequestID is a property of ActionRequest and not ARVM. I know for sure that if you replace your foreach loop with a for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.ARVM.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ARVM[i].RequestID)
}
```

or, I think, you can try to do this:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(item => item.RequestID)
```

inside your for each loop.

Comment: The column headers are not inside a loop